# Scan appears to work setting graph properties, but get error on property-read

Tags: graphs-and-networks, syntax

This is a self-contained version of something a bit bigger - going for brevity. It is a bit synthetic, but there are applications I have in mind where the {{1,2}} will be replaced with real data, more of it, and for a larger network.

```
g = CompleteGraph[4];

Scan[(PropertyValue[{g, #[[1]] <-> #[[2]] &}, EdgeWeight] = #[[1]] + #[[2]] &), {{1, 2}}]
```

The argument `{{1,2}}` passed at the end is a subset of what I want to `Scan` over (I expect that list of pairs to be large).

The `Scan` appears to work, but when I read the EdgeWeight value for node 1<->2 afterwards, thus:

```
PropertyValue[{g, 1 <-> 2}, EdgeWeight]
```

I get `$Failed`

If I do manually what I am trying to Scan, and then read it, it works

```
PropertyValue[{g, 1 <-> 2}, EdgeWeight] = 3;
PropertyValue[{g, 1 <-> 2}, EdgeWeight]

(returns 3).
```

Clearly there's something wrong with my Scan, but without an error message I can't tell what that is.

*Edit I am specifically looking to understand why my expression does not work. An edited working expression without indication of why my expression is flawed isn't instructive to me. For example, if my nested list of data at the end is shaped differently, ## is not going to work automatically.
Yes - I can live with an answer that says "that will never work, here's why", but I am mostly looking for explanations - not just something that works.*

I'd appreciate some pointers on Scan; if there's a better way to do it I'd like to know what that is.

Comment: Builtin properties like `EdgeWeight` have easier ways to set.  You can either `SetProperty[g, EdgeWeight -> {1,2,3}]` (for a graph with three edges), or explicitly assign to edges like `SetProperty[g, EdgeWeight -> {1<->2 -> 1, 2<->3 -> 2, 1<->3 -> 3}]`.  This only works for builtin properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g = CompleteGraph[4]; 
Scan[(PropertyValue[{g, UndirectedEdge @@ ##}, EdgeWeight] = Tr@##) &, {{1, 2}}]
PropertyValue[{g, 1 <-> 2}, EdgeWeight]
(* 3 *)
```

Comment: Check your syntax :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - looking for some input on why mine is bad as well.  The Scan expression doesn't evaluate. Double brace after ## should be single brace, then it works

Comment: @Paul_A Thanks. Something went bad in the copy/paste. Yours have a misplaced `)` and an spurious `&`

Comment: `Scan[(PropertyValue[{g, #[[1]] <-> #[[2]]}, 
     EdgeWeight] = #[[1]] + #[[2]]) &, {{1, 2}}]`

Comment: thanks for the always-helpful identification of the error - I'm still puzzled that if the expression is invalid MMA swallows it silently - maybe it's not invalid but is just asking MMA to do something **other than what I want** (if any readers know what was wrong with the Scan in the original question I'd appreciate the pointers)

Comment: @Paul_A [**MMa doesn't swallow it silently**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsvsv.png) here

Comment: that's interesting . .. @Belisarius-is-forth I just re-evaluated that expression and I am still getting silent failure. I am using Mathematica 10.1.0.0